# Run putty from java GUI app

Tags: java, putty

I want to build an application in java which would run/display putty in it in different tabs much like PuttyCM or super putty. is it possible in java any pointers?

I have just started learning java but i do have some programming knowledge.

Thanks
Bluestreak

Comment: Well, you're not going to run *PuTTY*, but you would have code that acts *like* PuTTY running in each tab.

Comment: well basically i just want to design a GUI which would ask for putty path and run it. will be adding some buttons to the outer frame to accomplish few things thats all. for example  http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/91972-embed-putty-in-gui/ or http://www.unixmantra.com/2013/04/putty-connection-manager-tabbed-putty.html . Those two example are in AHK and C# .Just need to know if its possible in java and how to go about it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how PuTTY is specifically written, nor with Windows' window management APIs.

Comment: anyone else got any idea?